# How to get the list of folders in ComboBox using FOR loop in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, list, directory, combobox

I am looking for a way to list subfolders in a set folder using FOr loop. I got this for files in folder like:

```
            For Each File As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("G:\100 Databases\ASSETS\FLAGS\JPG\")
                .Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File))
            Next
```

But how does this would be for folders

```
            For Each Folder As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(ClientsFolder)
                .Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Folder))
            Next
```

My  version just lists the ClientFolder subfolders number of times but not the actual subfolder name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Path` class just works on `Strings`. It doesn't know anything about actual files and folders. It just knows the conventions of file system paths. The `GetFileName` method will simply get everything after the last `"\"` delimiter, without distinguishing between file and folder paths. That's what you need to use:

```vb
.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Folder))
```

That said, there are more improvements you can make to that code.

Firstly, you should generally only use a namespace to qualify a type once. If you would need to use the same namespace twice or more, import that namespace instead. You can import a namespace project-wide on the *References* page of the project properties or you can import it at the file level at the top of the code, e.g.

```vb
Imports System.IO
```

and then:

```vb
For Each Folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(ClientsFolder)
    .Items.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(Folder))
Next
```

Next, it's generally preferable to make a single call to `AddRange` than it is to make multiple calls to `Add`. If you're adding individual items here and there then that's different but you should call `AddRange` rather than `Add` in a loop. It won't really make much, if any, difference in most cases but it's good to create good habits so you won't do the wrong thing when it does matter, e.g.

```vb
Dim folders = Directory.GetDirectories(clientsFolder)

For i = 0 To folders.getUpperBound(0)
    folders(i) = Path.GetFileName(i)
Next

.Items.AddRange(folders)
```

Notice that I have also used a lower-case character to start variable names. You don't have to do that but it's what Microsoft recommends and it's what the bulk of .NET developers do.

Next, it is often preferable to bind a list to a `ComboBox` rather than add items directly. For a simple list, it doesn't make too much difference, but it may be advantageous here. What you can do it use `DirectoryInfo` objects instead of simple `Strings`. You can then display the `Name` property, which is just the folder name, but still have access to the `FullName` property, which is the full path, e.g.

```vb
Dim clientsFolder = New DirectoryInfo(clientsFolderPath)
Dim subFolders = clientsFolder.GetDirectories()

.DisplayMember = NameOf(DirectoryInfo.Name)
.ValueMember = NameOf(DirectoryInfo.FullName)
.DataSource = subFolders
```

When the user selects a folder name, you can then get its full path from the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox`.

If you're doing this for files rather than folders then there is a `FileInfo` class that has the same properties, but it doesn't have a property that will remove the file extension. You can throw a bit of LINQ at the problem though, and make your own, e.g.

```vb
Dim filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(clientsFolderPath)

.DisplayMember = "NameWithoutExtension"
.ValueMember = "FullPath"
.DataSource = filePaths.Select(Function(s) New With {.FullPath = s, .NameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s)}).ToArray()
```

*More to follow...*

Comment: Yup I have imported "system.io"

Comment: @Eduards, you may like to check out my edits, which are more about improving your code than addressing the specific question asked.

Comment: Yup keeping up o date with your edits :)